# Developing platform independent app in Ubuntu using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am new to PhoneGap.I need to Develop an Application that should be platform independent(that should run in all platforms like Android,IOS,Windows) using PhoneGap.I have created a sample project for Android in Ubuntu is working fine but when I am building IOS for the same sample project showing this warning - "WARNING: Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - linux." How to create a project of IOS and windows in Ubuntu using PhoneGap.Please Help me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build the iOS version of a Phonegap app without access to XCode due to restrictions put in place by Apple.

You can use [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com) to build the iOS version, but to run it you'll still need to set up the various keys and certificates required.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Matthew.When I am running this command "cordova build ios" in Ubuntu, showing this error "Error: Source path does not exist: icon.png".Help me please.

Comment: You need to set this path in your config.xml and the file for the icon needs to exist at that path.

Comment: Its already there in config.xml and the icons exists in that path.

Comment: Matthew Can you help me please with the above Issue ?

Comment: Like I said, you cannot build it for iOS on anything other than Mac OS X. Either do it in Mac OS X or switch to Phonegap Build.

Comment: How to build IOS in PhoneGap in Ubuntu?

Comment: Again, you can not do this without Mac OS X or switching to Phonegap Build. You will need to read up on it at https://build.phonegap.com

Comment: Any other links would be appreciated Matthew.

Comment: When I am running this command "cordova build ios" in Ubuntu, showing this "Error: Source path does not exist: icon.png".

Comment: I'm sorry, how are you not getting this? That command will never work on anything other than Mac OS X.

Comment: how to Build PhoneGap IOS app in Linux ?  Please help me Matthew.

Comment: What? How can you possibly not get this? You cannot build an iOS app on Linux using Phonegap. At all. Ever. There is no way whatsoever to build it for iOS on Linux. Either use Phonegap Build or build it on a Mac - those are the two ways you can do it unless Apple make it possible to build it for iOS on Linux. Until then, those are the options. I can't help you do something that is physically impossible.

Comment: how to use IOS PhoneGap build in Linux ?

Comment: Phonegap Build is a web based service. Read the documentation for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Matthew.